# Opaque background in floating hint in TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I have to make a textinputlayout with the floating hint label, that needs to have a white background. Some what similar to this--

Design expected:

[image: Design expected]

But all I have been able to do so far is this:

Actual Design using TextInputLayout:

[image]

Currently the hint label in TextInputLayout have a transparent background.
Can anybody please help me and tell how to make this possible?

Here is my code (The texinput layout):

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/til_login_info"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/text_input_layout_background"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextStyle.Small.Hint">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login_info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:hint="Email / Mobile"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

And the background I am using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:top="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke

                android:width="1px"
                android:color="@color/Grey300" />
            <corners android:radius="100dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please share your code?

Comment: @RafiKamal I added the code I am using

Comment: Try `colorSurface` in the main App There
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54002965/textinputlayout-filledbox-boxbackgroundcolor-not-apply-alpha-channel

Answer (score 10):

You should use Material Design style for **Outline Box**. Just simple put:

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
```

to your `TextInputLayout`.

For rounded corners use:

```
boxCornerRadiusTopStart
boxCornerRadiusTopEnd
boxCornerRadiusBottomStart
boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd
```

See *Text Field for Android* in [Material Design Guide](https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-input-layout/)
[image]

Comment: I had same issue, after I applied this style, my hint is not showing. is there any different with outlinebox style and fillled box style?

Comment: @Menma put your hint to the `TextInputLayout` instead of `TextInputEditText`

Comment: I've put hint and`style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"` on the `TextInputLayout` but after I put this style, my hint is not showing. if I use default style, my hint is showing

Comment: I don't know without the code. Is `style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"` working well?

Comment: Yup... that style is working well, I have no Idea why on the `OutlinedBox`'s style, hint is not showing

Answer (score 5):

**Here is an workaround:**

> **1.** Design your `layout` structure as below:

**activity_test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <!-- Mobile number -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_input_field" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_dummy_hint_mobile_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:text="Mobile Number"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
            android:hint="Mobile Number"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/HintTextStyle">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_mobile_number"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Promo code -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_input_field" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_dummy_hint_promo_code"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:text="Promo Code"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
            android:hint="Promo Code"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/HintTextStyle">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_promo_code"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

> **2.** Use below drawable `bg_rounded_input_field.xml` for rounded corners.

**res/drawable/bg_rounded_input_field.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <stroke
        android:color="@android:color/black"
        android:width="2dp">
    </stroke>

    <corners
        android:radius="1000dp">
    </corners>

</shape>
```

> **3.** Use below `HintTextStyle` to `TextInputLayout` by adding attribute `app:hintTextAppearance="@style/HintTextStyle"`.

**res/values/styles.xml**

```
<style name="HintTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>
```

> **4.** Finally, in your `Activity` just `show/hide` the  `text_dummy_hint_mobile_number` and `text_dummy_hint_promo_code`
>   during `focus` change.
>
> FYI, I have used `Handler` with delay `100 millis` to
>   show the dummy hints `TextView` to sync with `TextInputLayout` hint text
>   `animation`.

**TestActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textDummyHintMobileNumber;
    TextView textDummyHintPromoCode;
    EditText editMobileNumber;
    EditText editPromoCode;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        textDummyHintMobileNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_dummy_hint_mobile_number);
        textDummyHintPromoCode = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_dummy_hint_promo_code);
        editMobileNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_mobile_number);
        editPromoCode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_promo_code);

        // Mobile number
        editMobileNumber.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

                if (hasFocus) {
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // Show white background behind floating label
                            textDummyHintMobileNumber.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }, 100);
                } else {
                    // Required to show/hide white background behind floating label during focus change
                    if (editMobileNumber.getText().length() > 0)
                        textDummyHintMobileNumber.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    else
                        textDummyHintMobileNumber.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });

        // Promo code
        editPromoCode.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

                if (hasFocus) {
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // Show white background behind floating label
                            textDummyHintPromoCode.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }, 100);
                } else {
                    // Required to show/hide white background behind floating label during focus change
                    if (editPromoCode.getText().length() > 0)
                        textDummyHintPromoCode.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    else
                        textDummyHintPromoCode.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~