# TextInputLayout FilledBox boxBackgroundColor not apply alpha channel

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, androidx

TextInputLayout boxBackgroundColor not apply alpha channel. This happened when I merge app to AndroidX. Before merging everything was working good.

When boxBackgroundColor is "#77ff0000" color appears as light red when I set boxBackgroundColor as transparent, color appears as white. It draws background like first fill with white color and then applies given boxBackgroundColor.

Gradle:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01' 
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha02'
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to set `colorSurface` in your theme. It must match the background color of underlying layout or you might get some other weird color. `TextInputLayout` internally combines `colorSurface` and `boxBackgroundColor`.

Source: `TextInputLayout#calculateBoxBackgroundColor()`

Example how to fix the problem:

```xml
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="textInputStyle">@style/MyTextInputLayout</item>
        <item name="colorSurface">#FFFFFFF</item>
</style>

 <style name="MyTextInputLayout" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
        <item name="boxBackgroundColor">#77FF0000</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This comment solved my problem, couldn't find anything about this before! Should be in the official docs.